# Using Stokes' theorem to calculate a surface integral

Tags: integration, stokes-theorem

Use Stokes' theorem to calculate the surface integral

$$\iint_D\text{curl}\,\mathbf F \cdot\mathrm d\mathbf S$$ where $\mathbf F(x, y, z) = (xz,xe^z,-y)$ and $S = \{(x,y,z):z=-1+x^2+y^2\ \text{and}\ z\leq0\}$, with positive orientation.

Since $z=0$, then $x^2+y^2=1$ and

$$\mathbf r(t) = (\cos(t),\sin(t),0) \\ \mathbf r'(t)=(-\sin(t),\cos(t),0)$$

So:

$$\begin{align}\iint_D\text{curl}\,\mathbf F\cdot\mathrm d\mathbf S &= \int_0^{2\pi} \mathbf F(\mathbf r(t))\cdot \mathbf r'(t)\,\mathrm dt \\ &= \int_0^{2\pi}\cos^2t\,\mathrm dt = \pi\end{align}$$

Could someone check if this is right?

Comment: @LaxmiNarayanBhandari because $z=0$ is the frontier. Then $0 = -1 + x^2 + y^2$

Comment: Yes it is correct.

Comment: @LaxmiNarayanBhandari instead of calculating surface integral of the curl of the vector field, OP is applying Stokes' theorem and finding line integral of the vector field on the boundary which is a unit circle at $z = 0$

Comment: @Math Got it. I was not able to imagine the surface, when I had commented. Thanks for the insight.